# Write-Verbose vs Write-Host in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

While I am using `Write-Verbose` in powershell command window I'm not getting anything in the console. However it is used by devops engineers in my team for continuous integration, build scripts.

What is the difference between `Write-Verbose` and `Write-Host`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference between the cmdlets (as of [powershell-v5.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v5.0)) is which stream they use to display information.  By default, the Verbose stream (4) is not visible *unless* you specify `-Verbose`, add `-Verbose` using the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` automatic dictionary to append the switch to all or specific cmdlets, or setting the `$VerbosePreference` automatic variable.

You can observe this stream behavior as such:

```
PS ~/> Write-Verbose -Message 'Just testing' -Verbose 4>$null
PS ~/> Write-Verbose -Message 'Just testing' -Verbose
VERBOSE: Just testing
```

Likewise, the `Write-Host` cmdlet uses the Information stream (6) which is also not visible by default, but `Write-Host` essentially became a wrapper for

```
Write-Information -InformationAction Continue
```

This stream has the same requirements as the `Verbose` stream to be seen with the preference variable being `$InformationPreference`.

You can additionally observe these objects by assigning their output:

```
PS ~/> $output = Write-Verbose -Message test -Verbose 4>&1
PS ~/> $output | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.VerboseRecord
Name                  MemberType   Definition
----                  ----------   ----------
Equals                Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode           Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType               Method       type GetType()
ToString              Method       string ToString()
WriteVerboseStream    NoteProperty bool WriteVerboseStream=True
InvocationInfo        Property     System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo InvocationInfo {get;}
Message               Property     string Message {get;set;}
PipelineIterationInfo Property     System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[int] PipelineIterationInfo

PS ~/> $output = Write-Host -Object test 6>&1
PS ~/> $output | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord
Name                   MemberType   Definition
----                   ----------   ----------
Equals                 Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode            Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType                Method       type GetType()
ToString               Method       string ToString()
WriteInformationStream NoteProperty bool WriteInformationStream=True
Computer               Property     string Computer {get;set;}
ManagedThreadId        Property     uint ManagedThreadId {get;set;}
MessageData            Property     System.Object MessageData {get;}
NativeThreadId         Property     uint NativeThreadId {get;set;}
ProcessId              Property     uint ProcessId {get;set;}
Source                 Property     string Source {get;set;}
Tags                   Property     System.Collections.Generic.List[string] Tags {get;}
TimeGenerated          Property     datetime TimeGenerated {get;set;}
User                   Property     string User {get;set;}
```

Valid values for the preference variables are as such:

```
[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference].GetEnumValues()
```

---

#### [`about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 6):

`Write-Verbose` Write to console only when the `-Verbose` Parameters is used.

`Write-Host` Write to the console anyway...

You need to add the `[CmdletBinding()]` to the file before the `Param` Section to enable the `-Verbose` Parameter...

See Example:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
)
Write-Verbose "Verbose"
Write-Host "Host"

PS C:\> .\test.ps1
Host
PS C:\> .\test.ps1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Verbose
Host
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the definitions

> **Write-Verbose**
> Writes text to the verbose message stream.
>
> **Write-Host**
> Writes customized output to a host.

I think your devops engineers would have set `$VerbosePreference = "Continue"` before running their scripts due to which the Verbose logs also output to the console.

Let's see an example

```
PS > Write-Verbose "hello"
> NO OUTPUT
PS > Write-Host "hello"
hello
PS >  $VerbosePreference = "Continue"
PS > Write-Verbose "hello"
VERBOSE: hello
```

The important thing to remember is that cmdlets like `Write-Verbose`, `Write-Error` etc. are for providing different *levels of logging* i.e. it is useful when you are monitoring the logs and want to filter by log-level. This answers questions like "How many errors did we get?"(`Write-Error`), "Is this function being called?" (`Write-Debug`)

In contrast, `Write-Host` could typically be for showing "Output" to the user on the progress of the cmdlet, asking for input etc.

**References:**

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-6
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 1):

`Write-Verbose` is only "active" when the `-Verbose` switch is passed to the cmdlet - otherwise, the assumption is that you don't want to see the messages that would otherwise be generated.

`Write-Host` outputs its data unconditionally, and bypasses the PowerShell pipeline.